# Show that the intersection of $U(n)$ with symmetric matrices is a submanifold of $U(n)$.

Tags: matrices, differential-topology, lie-groups

$U(n)$ is the group of unitary matrices, and $S(n)=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})|A^T=A\}$ are the symmetric matrices, both $U(n)$ and $S(n)$ are viewed as submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$. My question is how to show that their intersection $U(n)\cap S(n)$ is a submanifold of $U(n)$.

Comment: Define a map $f: \mathbb{C}^{n^{2}} \to \mathbb{C}^{n^{2}} \times \mathbb{C}^{n^{2}}$, $f(A) = (AA^{\dagger} - I, A^{T} - A)$. Try showing this map satisfies the conditions for the implicit function theorem at $(0,0)$. If it does, can you continue from here?

Comment: @Tom:  The codomain needs to be shrunk for this approach to work.  MathDiego:  Do you know that fixed point sets of involutions are submanifolds?  If so, consider $T:U(n)\rightarrow U(n)$ with $T(A) = A^t$.

Comment: @Jason I don't know this result about involution. But you remind me that in Differential geometry it is true that the fixed points of a isometry is a totally geodesic submanifold,  so if it is connected, it will be a submanifold.

Comment: @Math:  Given any Riemannian metric $g$ and any involution $T$, $T$ is an isometry in the metric $g+T^\ast g$.  I don't immediately see how to prove that $U(n)\cap S(n)$ is connected.

Comment: I think I have discovered a way. Use the metric induced from $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $A\rightarrow A^t$ is an isometry on $U(n)$ since it is an isometry on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. To see that $U(n)\cap S(n)$ is connected, write $U\in U(n)\cap S(n)$ as $U=A+iB$ where $A,B$ are real and symmetric, $U^*U=I,U=U^t$ implies $AB=BA$, so $A,B$ can be diagonalized simutaneously by a real orthogonal matrix $P$, and $P^tUP=D$, $D$ is diagonal with $e^{i\theta}$ in its diagonal, so we can show $U=VV^t,V$is unitary, this implies the connectivity since $U(n)$ is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the metric induced from $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$, then $A\rightarrow A^t$ is an isometry on $U(n)$. To see that $U(n)\cap S(n)$ is connected, write $U\in U(n)\cap S(n)$ as $U=A+iB$, $U^∗U=I,U=U^t$ implies $A,B$ are real and symmetric, and $AB=BA$, so $A,B$ can be diagonalized simutaneously by a real orthogonal matrix $P$, and $P^tUP=D, D=diag\{e^{i\theta_1},\cdots,e^{i\theta_n}\}$ . So we can show $U=PDP^t=PD^{\frac{1}{2}}P^tPD^{\frac{1}{2}}P^t=VV^t,V=PD^{\frac{1}{2}}P^t$,$V$ is unitary, a path from $V$ to I in $U(n)$ gives a path from $VV^t$ to $I$ in $U(n)\cap S(n)$, this show that that $U(n)\cap S(n)$ is connected.
By theorem in Riemann geometry that the fixed points of an isometry is a totally geodesic submanifold, I get what I try to prove.